# How can I iterate through a specific JSON item in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've done my best to implement other peoples similar questions from around the internet but haven't been successful. I am working on a simple app that displays the top 50 cryptocurrencies. The information I will show will be the symbol(BTC, ETH...) and price. For now I am just trying to show the symbol.

I am able to get the symbol for each coin individually by using Text(self.fetcher.publishedCoins?.data.coins[0].symbol ?? "") and changing the array index. Obviously I don't want to do that 50 times so I tried implementing ForEach but couldn't figure it out. Here's where I'm at...

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var fetcher = CoinFetcher()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            //Text(self.fetcher.publishedCoins?.data.coins[0].symbol ?? "Error Updating")

            //Attempting to iterate through Coin.symbol
            ForEach(self.fetcher.publishedCoins?.data.coins[Coin] ?? "") { select in
                Text(select.symbol)
            }
        }
    }
}}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

LoadJSON.swift

```
import Foundation

public class CoinFetcher: ObservableObject {
    
@Published var publishedCoins: Top?
    
init() {
    loadJSON()
}

func loadJSON() {
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.coinranking.com/v1/public/coins")!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data,response,error) in
        do {
            if let retrievedData = data {
                let webData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Top.self, from: retrievedData)
                print(Top.self)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.publishedCoins = webData
                }
            } else {
                print("No data loaded")
            }
        } catch {
            print ("Error here")
        }
    }.resume()
}
}
```

Coins.swift

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Top
struct Top: Codable {
    let status: String
    let data: Data
}

// MARK: - Data
struct Data: Codable {
    let coins: [Coin]
}

// MARK: - Coin
struct Coin: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let uuid: String
    let slug: String
    let symbol: String
    let name: String
    let confirmedSupply: Bool
    let volume: Int
    let marketCap: Int
    let price: String
    let circulatingSupply: Double
    let totalSupply: Double
    let approvedSupply: Bool
    let change: Double
    let rank: Int
    let history: [String?]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, uuid, slug, symbol, name, confirmedSupply, volume, marketCap, price, circulatingSupply, totalSupply, approvedSupply, change, rank, history
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can conform `Coin` to `Hashable`:

```
struct Coin: Codable, Hashable { ... }
```

you can try the following:

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        ForEach(self.fetcher.publishedCoins?.data.coins ?? [], id:\.self) { coin in
            Text(coin.symbol)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that as your data can change you need to use a dynamic `ForEach` loop (with an explicit `id` parameter)